# Apache Cordova InAppBrowser fullscreen mode

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

trying an application using Phonegap. I used the InAppBrowser on an android tablet:

```
var win = window.open(sampleURL, "_blank", "location=no");
```

But I'm having trouble on making it fullscreen (the title bar the top should not show at all) even if the config.xml has been set up with this line:

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

[image: Sample result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AndroidManifest.xml change/add the **theme**:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

for the **application** and the **activity** tags.

Answer (score 0):

In `config.xml` 
 add to `<platform name="android">` 
 `<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        </edit-config>`